# View pptx file in web browser

Tags: c#, html, node.js, angular, .net-core

I want to view pptx files in web browser that i have uploaded on a location using .net core.

> http://stepupsolution.com/PPTViewer/MonitorPPT1.pptx (approx 40 mb)
>
> http://stepupsolution.com/PPTViewer/MonitorPPT2.pptx (approx 4 mb)

When i am trying to view both the file using the below code, I can see the MonitorPPT2 file but when i am trying to open MonitorPPT1 file it shows me error "The file specified is larger than what the Office Viewers are configured to support."

```
<iframe src='http://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=http://stepupsolution.com/PPTViewer/MonitorPPT1.pptx' width='900px' height='600px' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

I have also tried and able to embed the pptx file using one drive for single file, but again my requirement is to display all files from a folder on my screen as a link and when i click, it should open in next window tab.I am getting stuck to communicate with one-dive folder using ms graph.

**Can anyone help me to communicate with one drive or any way to embed the large size pptx file with website?.**

Answer (score 1):

I think a quick solution would be to upload the powerpoint files to your server, and then set up a simple webpage with links to download them. Make sure to also include a link to download the freely available Powerpoint Viewer 2003 (from Microsoft) for those who may not have Powerpoint.

You may also want to show the file size of each .ppt file (possibly to the right of the download link for each file) as a courtesy to your users.

By the way, sliderocket.com 4 is a web-based Powerpoint competitor with share and embed capabilities that you may want to look into. It’s in beta and free at the moment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good suggestion, but if you don't install Powerpoint in the system, so you are not able to open the PPTX file after download.

Comment: My requirement is view pptx file in a new window tab not to download and open on any machine.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, PPTX files aren't showing directly on Web Page. So I suggest first convert PPTX to PDF and then show PDF file using iframe. If fulfill your requirements.

Comment: If I will change it in pdf, I may lost all video links and animated effects.

Comment: using an object tag is preferable over iframe for non-webpage embedded sources.